# iOS7 renderInContext does not capture png image with alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios7, uigraphicscontext

I'm working on the camera app that overlays images over the picture taken. It works perfectly on iOS5 and iOS6, but on iOS7, the images with alpha cannot be overlaid correctly. The overlaid images become completely opaque.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSizeMake( width, height ), NO, 0 );
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
NSData *data  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext());
UIImage* viewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It seems to be same problem as this, but in my case this solution did not work.
[CALayer renderInContext iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024785/calayer-renderincontext-ios7)

I confirmed that on iOS7 drawViewHierarchyInRect does work, but this new method requires Xcode 5 to build. Is there any simpler workaround?

Comment: Have you tried calling drawViewHierarchyInRect via NSInvocation in Xcode 4 rather than by a direct call? Seems like it should work.

Comment: I tried but @selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) seems to be nil without iOS7 SDK, so I couldn't call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put the image in a seperate UIImageView, and just set the View's alpha?

Comment: Since I must use each pixel's alpha-channel in png images, setting alpha for the view itself doesn't work in this case. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?